# My enter button won't push items to list (React JS)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So I'm trying to create a list app using React. I don't have any errors or warnings, and my input bar is showing, but my textList won't render. In other words when ever I hit enter, the text info I put in the input bar won't create a list as expected.
I tried using keyCode === 13 and onKeyDown, but it's not having any effect on the app. What am I missng?

Here's my code:

filtered-input.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./filtered-input.css";
import ItemList from "./item-list";

export class FilteredInput extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
   this.state = {
   textList: [],
  };
 }


handleChange(e) {
this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
}

handleAdd = (e) => {
if (e.keyCode === 13) {
  let lists = this.props.state.textList;
  lists.push(this.props.state.value);
  this.setState({ textList: lists });
 }
};

render() {

console.log("Here comes state -->");
console.log(this.state);

return (
  <div>
    <input
      className="filtered-input-box"
      type="text"
      onKeyDown={this.props.handleAdd}
      value={this.state.value}
      onChange={this.props.handleChange}
    />
    <ItemList item={this.state.textList}></ItemList>
  </div>
  );
 }
}
```

ItemList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export class ItemList extends Component {
render() {
const items = this.props.item.map((item) =>
    <li>{item}</li>
);

return (
        <ul>
            {items}
        </ul>
    );
   }
 }

export default ItemList;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FilteredInput } from './filtered-input.js';

export class App extends Component {
  render() {

    return (

        <div>

            <p>This page demonstrates a component that maintains its own state.</p>

            <FilteredInput />


        </div>

      );

     }

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

There were small syntactical mistakes here and there, apart from that everything looks perfect:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>This page demonstrates a component that maintains its own state.</p>

        <FilteredInput />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class FilteredInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      textList: [],
      value: ""
    };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  };

  handleAdd = e => {
    console.log("hi");
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      let lists = this.state.textList;
      lists.push(this.state.value);
      this.setState({ textList: lists });
    }
  };

  render() {
    console.log("Here comes state -->");
    console.log(this.state);

    return (
      <div>
        <input
          className="filtered-input-box"
          type="text"
          onKeyDown={this.handleAdd}
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <ItemList item={this.state.textList} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ItemList extends Component {
  render() {
    const items = this.props.item?.map(item => <li>{item}</li>);

    return <ul>{items}</ul>;
  }
}
```

Full working app : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vpj3bm?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: It works! but only if I don't include the "?" in the const items variable. What is the purpose of it???

Comment: ```?.``` it is called optional chaining, you can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining